# Injecting the category of finitely presented categories into various categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

I am thinking of the ways $Cat_f$, the category of finitely presented categories, can be injected into various other categories.  Specifically, I am interested in giving a specific definition of the functor from $Cat_f$ to a given category, $M$ which supports a faithful functor $F: Cat_f \rightarrow M$.  I want to say that this functor is defined by taking the objects of $Cat_f$, getting the morphisms of each category $C$ in $Cat_f$, and all the equations of $C$, and mapping the morphisms of $C$ to morphisms in $M$.  So, each category $C$ in $Cat_f$ generates a map of all the morphisms in $C$ to morphisms in $M$, we call this collections of morphisms in $M$, $C$-clusters.  We require that the $C$-clusters reproduce the compositions and equations of $C$ on the nose.  We will further want to "see" the morphisms of $Cat_f$ (namely functors between categories) as some other kind of relationship between the $C$-clusters. Is this a correct way to define the functor $F$?  Is this a well know construction?  Is the assumption of a faithful functor correct?

[I asked about this over at math stack but got no response](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4205603/7062)

Comment: You should mention that you previously asked the question on Math Stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4205603/7062